# Fano's inequality explained intuitively?

Tags: probability, information-theory

I am now reading through a book to understand Fano's inequality, but I remember my professor explaining it in a certain way that made it seem so logical.

I will go office hours as soon as possible, but for now can someone please try to explain to me Fano's inequality but not through math just in a "logical" way that makes sense.

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Suppose that we wish to estimate a random variable $X$, by an estimator $\hat{X}$ . Further
more assume that $\mathbb{P}(\hat{X} \neq X) = \epsilon$. The question is what can we say about the conditional entropy $H(X\mid\hat{X})$. Intuitively, if $\epsilon$ is very small, then $H(X\mid\hat{X})$ should also be very small. Fano's inequality quantiﬁes this intuition
$$
H(X\mid\hat{X})\leq H\left(\epsilon\right)+\epsilon\log\left(|\mathcal{X}\right|-1)
$$
where $\mathcal{X}$ is the *alphabet* of $X$, and $|\mathcal{X}|$ is the cardinality of $\mathcal{X}$.

You can find more information in this [book](http://books.google.co.il/books?id=EuhBluW31hsC&printsec=frontcover&dq=information%20theory&client=firefox-a&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=information%20theory&f=false).

Answer (score 24):

I encourage you to think in terms of how many bits you need to transmit in order to know $X$ (a random variable) from $\hat{X}$ (an estimate).

$H(X|\hat{X})$ is the average number of bits we need to transmit so the receiver can know $X$ with the knowledge of $\hat{X}$. We want to upper bound this.

Imagine we use up some bits in communicating if $X$ is $\hat{X}$ or not. The distribution for this is $\{P_e,1-P_e\}$, i.e we need to transmit $H(P_e)$ bits on an average to do this.

If it's NOT $\hat{X}$, then it could be any one of the other $|\mathcal{X}|-1$ symbols in the alphabet. The WORST case length is now $\log(|\mathcal{X}|-1)$ and this happens with a probability $P_e$.

So we have,
$$H(X|X') \le H(P_e)+P_e\log(|X|-1) \le H(P_e)+P_e\log(|X|) $$

Answer (score 1):

How many bits could measure $ X $ from $\hat{X}$? 
Of course, the more, the better. 
However, we want to upper bound the bits.
First we want to use $ H(P_{e}) $ bits to show whether $\hat{X}$ is right or not.If it is right, no more bits are needed.Or we must use $\log \left| \chi -1 \right|$ bits to distinguish the error.
Finally, $ H(P_{e}) +$ $0\cdot(1-P_{e})$ + $\log \left| \chi -1 \right|\cdot P_{e}$ is the upper bound.